# On the definition of a linear projection map

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathbb P^n$ be a hyperplane in $\mathbb P^{n+1}$ and let $P \in \mathbb P^{n+1} -\mathbb P^n$. Then the mapping defined by $\phi :\mathbb P^{n+1} -\{P\} \to \mathbb P^n$ given by $\phi(Q) :=$ the intersection of the unique line containing $P$ and $Q$ with $\mathbb P^n$. This is known as *Projection from a point*.

At this point my question is that : Let $X \subset \mathbb P^n$ a projective variety. Then what is the definition of a linear projection map $\pi : X \to \mathbb P^{\text{dim}X}$ ?

If we consider points of $X$ to be that of $\mathbb P^n$ and use the definition mentioned at the beginning we land in $\mathbb P^n$, not necessarily in $\mathbb P^{\text{dim}X}$. Does this mean there is no relation between these two concepts?

Can someone give me a precise reference?

Any help from anyone is welcome.

Comment: A general linear subspace $L\subset \mathbb{P}^n$ of dimension $n-\dim X-1$ does not intersect $X$. So, for any point $Q\in X$, the linear space got by joining $Q$ to $L$ (called the join $J(L,Q)$ of $L,Q$) meets $X$ only in $Q$. So, the projection from $L$ to $\mathbb{P}^{\dim X}=P\subset \mathbb{P}^n$ for a general $P$, defined as $P\mapsto J(L,Q)\cap P$ makes sense and is called the linear projection.

Comment: @Mohan, I think you meant projection from $X$ to $\mathbb P^{dimX}$ is defined by $Q \mapsto J(L,Q) \cap \mathbb P^{dimX}$. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Isn't that what I said? Just to avoid typing too much I denoted by $P=\mathbb{P}^{\dim X}$.

Comment: Oh, I understand. Correcting my typo, it should be $Q\mapsto J(L,Q)\cap P$.

Comment: @Mohan this seems like an answer to me - would you care to record it below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general linear subspace $⊂\mathbb{P}^n$ of dimension $n−\dim X−1$ does not intersect $X$. So, for any point $Q\in X$, the linear space got by joining $Q$ to $L$ (called the join $J(L,Q)$ of $L,Q$) meets $X$ only in $Q$. So, the projection from $L$ to $\mathbb{P}^{\dim X}=P\subset\mathbb{P}^n$ for a general $P$, defined as $Q\mapsto J(L,Q)\cap P$ makes sense and is called the linear projection.